# Conductivity of a heavily doped semiconductor at Absolute zero temperature

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

As the Fermi level moves toward the conduction band in an n-type semiconductor; when heavily doped, it moves into the conduction band of the semi conductor. So, will the semi conductor behave as a conductor at that point and if so, will it be a superconductor?

Comment: Highly doped semi-conductor behaves as a conductor. Whether it is a superconductor or not is different question.

Comment: @DavidSaykin yeah, but at Absolute zero, conductors are superconductors, so will a semiconductor also behave as such?

Comment: at absolute zero some metals (conductors, semi-conductors and insulators) are superconductors and some are not. For example, Al is superconductor and Cu is not.

Comment: When _degenerately_ doped the dopant levels may merge with the conduction band. Otherwise, at T=0 the Fermi level is never in the conduction band.